# Wordpress: How to insert a banner inside gallery shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, gallery

I have picture galleries in wordpress with 12 pics per gallery and I'd like to insert a banner after 6 pics (html with href, would be best if I could use custom fields) . Is this possible? Does anyone knows a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a custom field. What plugin are you using?